# Python Mocks for if-else and os Module

Tags: python, mocking, python-unittest

I have the following code and I tried every way to mock the entire function, but coverage seems to miss the else block. Searched on SO, but no solution helped my case. Kinda wrapping my head around mocks, and is tough. Any help or rather explanation would help. Thanks.

```
# module.py (main function in a separate class)

def get_log_filename(filepath, filename, env):
   if os.path.exists(filepath):
      logs = filepath+filename+env+".log"
   else:
      os.mkdir(filepath)
      logs = filepath+filename+env+".log"
   return logs
```

### Test Case below

```
test_module.py

import unittest
import module
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):
      
    def setUp(self):
        self.logpath = os.path.join('/home')
        self.logconfigpath = os.path.join('/home/config')
        self.logfile = 'test_case_run'
        self.logdata = module('dev', self.logpath, self.logfile, self.logconfigpath) # because the original module is a class and has __init__
    
    @patch('module.os')
    @patch.object(module, 'get_log_filename', return_value = 'filename.log')
    def test_log_file_name(self, mockpath, mockext):
        mockext.path.exists.return_value = True
        module.get_log_filename()
        self.assertEqual(module.get_log_filename(), "filename.log")


    @patch('module.os')
    @patch.object(module, 'get_log_filename', return_value = 'filename.log')
    def test_log_file_names(self, mockpath, mockos):
        mockos.path.exists.return_value = False
        module.get_log_filename()
        mockos.mkdir()
        self.assertEqual(module.get_log_filename(), "filename.log")
```

The above test_module succeeds, but coverage does not cover the else block of the main function.
Can anyone let me know where i am going wrong and how does this even work?

Comment: Don't patch the function you want to test. Otherwise, all you are testing is that `unittest.mock` works. You need to call the *actual* `get_log_filename` function.

Comment: okay, Its working now, Thanks to @Antonio Quarta ; but have a doubt .. Can an entire function be mocked? ie.. instead of running the function, i mock that also ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With `@patch.object(module, 'get_log_filename', return_value = 'filename.log')` line
you are mocking the `get_log_filename`, that is the function to be tested.

I've correct the test in this way:

```py
# module.py (main function in a separate class)
import os

def get_log_filename(filepath, filename, env):
   if os.path.exists(filepath):
      print(1)
      logs = filepath+filename+env+".log"
   else:
      os.mkdir(filepath)
      logs = filepath+filename+env+".log"
   return logs
```

### Test case below

```py
#test_module.py

import unittest
import module
from unittest.mock import Mock, patch, MagicMock
import os

class TestModule(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        self.logpath = os.path.join('/home')
        self.logconfigpath = os.path.join('/home/config')

    @patch('module.os')
    def test_log_file_name(self, mockext):
        mockext.path.exists.return_value = True
        res = module.get_log_filename(self.logpath, "filename.log", self.logpath)
        self.assertEqual(res, "filename.log")


    @patch('module.os')
    def test_log_file_names(self, mockos):
        mockos.path.exists.return_value = False
        res = module.get_log_filename(self.logpath, "filename.log", self.logpath)
        mockos.mkdir.assert_called_once()
        self.assertEqual(res, "filename.log")
```

```
PS C:\stack_overflow> coverage report -m
Name             Stmts   Miss  Cover   Missing
----------------------------------------------
module.py            8      0   100%
test_module.py      17      0   100%
----------------------------------------------
TOTAL               25      0   100%
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. i have a question, could be lame, the variable "res", does it actually call the real function or is it a mock meaning should the parameters of the function be actual values or can be fake ones?

Comment: I see something weird, the original function "get_log_filename(filepath, filename, env)", has 3 arguments, and in the test script, in the res line,  when I pass a value, I get this error --> get_log_filename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'env' ..  I have edited the test script in the main post under setup method.

Comment: "res" will contain what the "get_log_filename" returns.

I don't get what you mean in the second comment, but when you call the get_log_filename you have to pass the right number of parameters, in this case 3:
(filepath, filename, env)

Comment: correct, parameters is 3,

1) Should those parameters be actual values or can be it dummy that doesnt make sense to the function. , in other words, does the function actually run or is it faking the run? Because i passed 3 values to my script and i get this
error --  get_log_filename() missing 1 required positional argument: 'env'  (FYI, i have modified the test script in the post, request you to check that once)

2) If its actually running, what is the point of mocking? i know we are mocking only the module.os, but can the function run also be mocked?

Comment: The function should be actually ran. Only the module.os is mocked. Isn't clear to me why that error appears.